# Visual Studio 2013 Community weird errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed Visual Studio Community 2013 with update 4 and when I try to build my project I get these errors(see below):

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(362,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\sal_supp.h(57): warning C4005: '__useHeader' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sal.h(2886) : see previous definition of '__useHeader'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\specstrings_supp.h(77): warning C4005: '__on_failure' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sal.h(2896) : see previous definition of '__on_failure'
```

How to solve them? I tried many ways but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel and go to uninstall program.

[image: uninstall]

Choose your visual studio community edition update 4.  Select change or repair, if it's there. If it opens to the Visual Studio window then select repair there.

[image: controlPanelChoice]

Select repair.

[image: VSRepair]

Keep your internet connection on while you do this, so your sdk and platform tools can be updated.

If this doesn't work, there are some links to altering the registry:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478856/3956566

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48a4500c-2c48-43dd-822b-10e83258d18b/warning-msb8003-could-not-find-windowssdkdir-variable-from-the-registry-targetframeworkversion-or?forum=visualstudiogeneral

[How to set SGEN toolpath in Msbuild to target 3.5 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748974/how-to-set-sgen-toolpath-in-msbuild-to-target-3-5-framework/5701714#5701714)

https://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=457

Comment: Still the same problem.