# Failure to build open62541 with CMake on Windows

Tags: c, windows, cmake, build, open62541

I am trying to build the library on Windows with CMake. The whole process is new to me, so please excuse this basic question. I followed the instructions under 2.1.2 of the current open62541 manual (Release 1.2.0-rc2-45-gf4270ceb). After executing `cmake.exe`, I got the following error:

```
<path-to>\open62541\build>"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19043.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The German sentence towards the end translates to `The system cannot find the specified file`.

I have found several files called `MSBuild.exe` on my computer and added them all to the PATH environment. This has not resolved the issue.

I tried using the prebuilt single files, but as far as I understand, these are for Linux systems and can not be used with Windows, correct?

Any inputs how I can proceed to obtain a working build are highly appreciated. Thanks!

[Edit:] I was able to continue the build process by doing two things:

- Changed the Visual Studio Version to the current one in the command (`Visual Studio 16 2019`)
- Installed the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019345/i-just-installed-visual-studio-and-ran-into-some-errors-specifically-the-windows).

Now I am stuck at the step where is says in the manual "Then open `buildopen62541.sln` in Visual Studio 2015 and build as usual." Any hints what exactly I am supposed to do?

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe/47258066) about the same error message and its answers? The option `-G "Visual Studio 14 2015"` means to configure the project for Visual Studio 14. Do you have Visual Studio of **exactly that version**?

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I was able to solve it based on inputs from that question. See my edit for details.

Comment: Invocation of `cmake` creates a solution file `buildopen62541.sln`. You need to run your Visual Studio and open that file in it.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but I am unsure if the process was successful. Is it normal that I don't see anything happening in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Visual Studio on an `.sln` file means to open it in VS, then click on `Build` in the menu bar and then on `Build solution`.
This was new for me, thanks everyone for hinting me in the right direction.